# Evaluation of m.v is blocked by applying MatrixForm. Why?

Tags: matrix, output-formatting

I'm trying to understand what is happening in the notebook session below.

I have a 2x2 matrix `m = {{-1,-1}, {-1,-1}}`.

And a vector `v ={1,1}`.

`m.v` (not shown) gives `{-2,-2}` as expected, and applying `MatrixForm` to `m`, to `v`, and to `m.v` gives presents the 3 values in the form I would expect.

However, if `MatrixForm` is applied to `m` and `v` prior to evaluating `m.v` (as shown) then both `mm.vv` and `mm.vv` give the same unexpected result -- what appears to be then "unevaluated" product.  (And possibly the wrong "kind" of product: "m dot v", rather than "m times v".)

I realize there are (probably related) issues around Mathematica not actually operating in terms of "column vectors", and instead doing some more general tensor based operation.  I'm in the process of trying to understand all that as well.  But my basic question here is what exactly `MatrixForm` is doing.

I thought that is was simply a presentation-level operation, but it appears that is not the case?

[image: MatrixForm, applied after and before]

Comment: Take a look at point 6. in [Common pitfalls - Basic syntax issues](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/5478)

Comment: The documentation for `MatrixForm` is unfortunately a bit misleading. The statement that it *"..."acts as a "wrapper", which affects printing, but not evaluation"* implies that it is somehow transparent to the evaluator. As you have found, this is not actually the case. Like `Subscript`, `MatrixForm` is something you should reserve for pretty output formatting, but keep out of the internals of your code.

Comment: Thanks everyone, (@eldo included), this is very helpful.   In case anyone else ends up here in the future -- I see now that evaluating `FullForm[m]` and 'FullForm[mm]` in my example is also enlightening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evaluate Head@mm - There's the answer :)